# Каким образом оценивать сложность алгоритма в нотации О-больше?

Tags: алгоритм, javascript

Алгоритм поиска корня числа num. В алгоритме также используется sqrt, это приблизительный корень.

```
function getsqrt (num, sqrt) {
  sqrt = 0.5*(sqrt+num/sqrt);
  var sqrtPrev = sqrt;
  while (Math.abs(sqrt-sqrtPrev) <= (sqrt-sqrtPrev)) {
    sqrtPrev = sqrt;
    sqrt = 0.5*(sqrt+num/sqrt);
  }
  return sqrt;
}
```

Какова сложность алгоритма? Линейная? Логарифмическая и т.д? Меня смущает просто деления на 2. Мне кажется, это линейная O(n)или логарифмическая.

**Обновление**

Мои рассуждения следующие: мы имеем один цикл, значит степень первая. Но я не уверен, что это линейная типа O(n). Потому что в задании есть 0.5*(sqrt+num/sqrt). Соответственно мне кажется, что это ускоряет поиск корня, нежели мы бы делили просто на 2 или методом перебора. Прав ли я, что это логарифмическая зависимость по основанию 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для Вашей функции сложно судить, какая у нее сложность - у Вас два аргумента. Поэтому, нужно либо фиксировать один аргумент, либо вводить зависимость между ними.

Я использовал простое - `sqrt = num/2`. и пошел по самому простому пути - тестил на разных значениях аргумента и построить график (это один из способов узнать сложность). Мое мнение - сложность константная (или очень близка к ней).

```
num  десятые микросекунды (10^-7)
1 -> 32
2 -> 27
4 -> 24
8 -> 24
16 -> 23
32 -> 23
64 -> 23
128 -> 26
256 -> 24
512 -> 23
1024 -> 23
2048 -> 24
4096 -> 23
8192 -> 23
16384 -> 23
32768 -> 22
65536 -> 23
131072 -> 24
262144 -> 23
524288 -> 23
1048576 -> 24
2097152 -> 23
4194304 -> 24
8388608 -> 23
16777216 -> 23
33554432 -> 24
67108864 -> 23
134217728 -> 23
268435456 -> 24
536870912 -> 24
```

Как видно на первых проходах идет "прогрев" (это отрабатывает jit компилятор).

Кстати, в Вашем коде есть одна ошибка - он иногда зависает. И зависает, если попытаться извлечь корень из числа, для которого он рациональный. (как минимум зависает на 4 и 10000).

полный код для тестов и исправление (все тестилось на node.js).

```
function getsqrt (num, sqrt) {
  sqrt = 0.5*(sqrt+num/sqrt);
  var sqrtPrev = sqrt;
  while (Math.abs(sqrt-sqrtPrev) < (sqrt-sqrtPrev)) {
    sqrtPrev = sqrt;
    sqrt = 0.5*(sqrt+num/sqrt);
  }
  return sqrt;
}

function test(num)
{
    var start = new Date();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        getsqrt(num, num / 2);
    }
    var end = new Date();
    return end.setTime(end.getTime()-start.getTime())
}

for (var i = 1; i < 1000000000; i = i*2) {
  console.log(i + " -> " + test(i));
}
```

P.S. В тегах указано с++, а код написан на JavaScript. Поэтому свой код я написал также на JavaScript.

**Обновление**

я разобрался, почему она константа. Потому что цикл обычно выполняется 1 раз или 0 (так у меня получается). Присмотритесь к условию

```
while (Math.abs(sqrt-sqrtPrev) <= (sqrt-sqrtPrev))
```

`sqrt-sqrtPrev` используется в обеих частях! А если вспомните, то есть такое правило - не сравнивать на равенство вещественные числа (на больше-меньше можно, но осторожно, если числа близкие).

Если там равно, то оно сработает только в том случае, если `sqrt-sqrtPrev > 0` и немного повезет (на самом деле, если разница представима конечной двоичной дробью).

Поэтому, сложность у алгоритма константная:).

Comment: @KoVadim если сложность приближается к константной, то выходит что она логарифмическая?! Я знаю, что он иногда не работает, но задания написать вот так.

Comment: нет, она не логарифмическая. И она не приближается к константной, а похоже что она ею является (если подумать, то понятно почему).

Если функция не работает на некоторых значениях, то в этих точках ее сложность возрастает до бесконечности.

Comment: @KoVadim, соглашусь, но в задании оценить сложность не на n числе вызова функции, а только один раз ее вызывать и оценить счетчик проходов по циклу, который внутри getsqrt(). (знаю, что что-то не так в задании).

Comment: @KoVadim, а если бы там было условия while (Math.abs(sqrt-sqrtPrev) > esp), где esp = 1e-10? Мой тест на getsqrt(5, 2). Показал, что проход по циклу идет только 1 раз. Также я проверил на других числах 10 и 9, 25 и 4. Все равно проход 1 раз.

Comment: Да, я тоже решил посмотреть (просто печатать сколько раз цикл выполняется) и удивился сначала, что всегда 1 раз.

Странный какой-то алгоритм. Неправильный, наверное.

Comment: @avp. такое задания. И что интересно, ответ совпадает с правильным.

Answer (score 2):

Если чуть-чуть изменить приведенный фрагмент программы следующим образом:

```
function getsqrt (num, sqrt) {
  var sqrtPrev = sqrt;
  sqrt = 0.5*(sqrt+num/sqrt);
  while (Math.abs(sqrt-sqrtPrev) > 1e-5) {
    sqrtPrev = sqrt;
    sqrt = 0.5*(sqrt+num/sqrt);
  }
  return sqrt;
}
```

То получившаяся программа будет реализацией известного [метода Ньютона](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) для отыскания корня уравнения `x^2 - num = 0`.

Про метод Ньютона известно, что (в некоторой окрестности решения) он обладает *квадратичной сходимостью*. Это означает, что на каждом следующем шаге значение невязки `diff`, то есть разности между значением `sqrt` и квадратным корнем из `num`, меньше, чем квадрат невязки, вычисленной на предыдущем шаге.

Число итераций цикла зависит как от величины числа `num`, так и от величины требуемой точности. В примере эта величина фиксирована: `1e-5`, но допустим, что она также может меняться. Обозначим требуемую точность именем `eps`. Тогда для метода Ньютона можно дать оценку числа итераций `O(log log (num/eps))`.